# External HTTP Call Completing But ASPX Page Not Loading After Upgrade to .NET Framework 4.7.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, timeoutexception

Upgraded my WebForms application from .NET Framework 4.6.2 to .NET Framework 4.7.1. Due to this upgrade my code that makes two http calls (one to get bearer token and one to get records) is preventing my application from finishing a web request for a page.

So for example I created a default WebForms .NET 4.7.1 App in Visual Studio 2019. I modified the `Default.aspx.cs` file to run my code on page load. I am able to reproduce the behavior here as well that when the application is started the page never loads once this code is ran.

In Fiddler I can see the request just hanging:
[image: Hung request]

I tried to deploying my upgraded app out on one of our servers and I saw in the Event Log that there was a Timeout exception. Not getting that locally, just the issue with the page not loading. What has changed between .NET framework 4.6.2 and 4.7.1 that is breaking HTTP Calls like this and how do I fix it?

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var fooBar = ProcessDataThruExternalApi("foo").Result;
            Console.WriteLine(fooBar);
        }

        private async Task<ExternalRecord> ProcessDataThruExternalApi(string customQueryString)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                string serviceUrl = "http://example.com:31010/ExApi";

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(serviceUrl);

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpRequestMessage tokenRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "token");
                tokenRequest.Content = new StringContent("key=" + "secretKey", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                return await client.SendAsync(tokenRequest)

                .ContinueWith(responseTask =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var responseObject = responseTask.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                        var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(responseObject);

                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(token))

                        {
                            //Add token to header
                            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("authorization", string.Format("bearer {0}", token));

                            //Call external api to get the data 
                            var response = client.GetAsync(string.Format("{0}ExternalRecords/ExternalSearch?customQueryString={1}", serviceUrl, customQueryString)).Result;
                            var externalRecord = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExternalRecord>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

                            //if resoponse failed then log exception
                            if (response != null && (response.IsSuccessStatusCode == false))
                            {
                                //Log the External returned errors 
                                Console.WriteLine(response);

                            }

                            return externalRecord;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (System.Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error occured while sending message to External API through ProcessDataThruExternalApi");

                    }
                    return null;
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this two calls are on the same web server ? (same url) Probably something is lock the other call, check the session lock, they block each other if its on the same host

Comment: @Aristos Yes same web server. But it was working as-is in .NET Framework 4.6.2. When I debug I can see the call to get a token is finishing and the call to get data returns as well but when I let debugging continue then that's when I notice the issue.  How do I check the "session lock" as you suggested?

Comment: @Aristos Updated Title and OP. Just to be clear, the EXTERNAL Http call is completing but the internal call to `Default.aspx` is not completing. If I remove the call to `ProcessDataThruExternalApi` from the `Page_Load` method the `Default.aspx` page does load. This behavior of the page not loading with `ProcessDataThruExternalApi` in the `Page_Load` method is a result of upgrade to .Net Framework 4.7.1. Understand?

Comment: I suggest to remove the `async` - the async have a meaning on desktop to avoid hang up the user interface from redraw. In web and in iis you do not have anything to hold, they all ready run on a thread.

Answer (score 1):

[Don't block on async code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) - that can cause deadlocks.

Instead, replace all calls to `.Result` or `.Wait()` with `await`:

```
protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var fooBar = await ProcessDataThruExternalApi("foo");
  Console.WriteLine(fooBar);
}
```

Note that to use `async` event handlers, you need to [ensure you're targeting 4.5 or newer in your web.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net#before-getting-started), and [opt into asynchronous handling by setting `Page.Async` to `true`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net#current-state-of-async-support).